# Long lasting loading in init procedure

Tags: long-integer, init

My app is loading a large file and it needs a lot of time for building up internal structures. After a while the app is terminetd by the OS  beuacuse of time out.
Any idea to handle it differently?

Answer (score 0):

My solution: As the last statement I create a timer, which is called 2 sec later. Then the remaining part is done.